# TS2345 Argument of type ... Is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

I have a lazy loaded store that is returning a specific selectors with the entire application store (ie it is not reduced).  The other selectors in this index.ts are reduced correctly.  When I try to call this selector from a component:

```
this.store.select(getBpFailed).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
})
```

I get a typescript error that says:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(state: State) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type ...[entire store model]
```

Another odd thing is that when I hover over the selector (in this case getBpFailed) the type hinting does not define it as a MemorizedSelector, where other (working) selectors they are defined as a MemorizedSelector.

Thoughts on how to debug?  I've been banging my head off the wall for too long on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was referencing the reducer getBpFailed method directly in my component, rather then using the selector in the index.ts file.  Thus I was getting the entire store because it wasn't reduced yet.  Dumb!  Hope this helps anyone else that makes the same mistake.